# Accessing localStorage from js file cached by ServiceWorker

Tags: local-storage, service-worker

I know that you can't access localStorage from ServiceWorker, however I can't find any info that matches my use case.

- I have `index.html`, `sw.js`, and `logic.js`
- `index.html` "loads" the
  service worker (`sw.js`)
- All service worker does is caches
  `index.html` and `logic.js` files for offline availability (has
  "install", "activate", and "fetch" listeners implemented)
- All
  business logic is in `logic.js` file; which is using localStorage

**Everything works fine, I just want to make sure there aren't any problems with this approach.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's fine, yes.

You can think about the service worker as proxying the network requests that are made for `logic.js` and any other resources/subresources. Once the network request is done, the service worker is effectively "out of the picture" (the thread that it's running in will actually stop unless there are active events).

The fact that the service worker was involved in loading `logic.js` does not prevent you from using local storage or doing anything else from within `logic.js`.